# Error handling for async/await in JS: which one is the preferred way?

Tags: javascript, async-await

For error handling in async/await in JavaScript, normally I see people use try catch to handle this.

e.g.

```js
async function apiCall() {
  throw new Error('failed')
}

async function run() {
  try {
    const response = await apiCall() 
    if(response.status === 'success') {
      console.log('success!')
    }
  } catch(e) {
    console.log('e', e)
  }
}
```

I never really liked try-catch block then I recently happened to know there is another way to handle it without relying on try-catch block

```js
async function run2() {
  const response = await apiCall().catch(console.log)
  if(!response) return
  if(response.status === 'success') {
    console.log('success!')
  }
}
```

But the downside is that it will continue executing the following lines even if there is an error so we have to manually return in the case of an error.

I wonder which way is better or in which cases one is preferred over the other?

Comment: Another downside of the second approach is that if `apiCall()` returns `undefined` in a normal case, it won't be distinguishable from the `undefined` that your `.catch()` handler returns. Sometimes that works, but sometimes it doesn't.

Comment: thanks that is a good point!